# how do I save a password on a file using UNIX/LINUX?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I only know how to read a password. But I'm having a problem on how to set a password inputted by the user for a file. I've only gone this far. Please help:

```
if [ -d "$1" ]
then
    #reads password
    read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
    stty -echo
    stty echo
    echo ""
    echo ""
    #checks whether the password is valid or not
    echo $mypassword" == "$PASS" ] && echo "Password accepted" || echo "Access denied"
else
    echo "Directory not found."
fi
```

Comment: So, what's the precise question? Note that UNIX/Linux typically use only rwxrwxrwx-style file access control: your account is the only factor that determines whether you have access to a file.

Comment: To expand on MSalters comment, you need to say what mechanism you are using to en-/de-crypt the file or filesystem. Only then do we have anyway of know how the passwords (or hopefully their hashes) are stored. If you don't know the answer to this question then it is possible that your system does not even have the capacity built-in. You might have to roll your own, and *that* is a whole 'nother can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't get you wrong, try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPECTED_PASS="FooBar"

if [ -d "$1" ]
then
    read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
    stty -echo
    stty echo
    echo ""
    echo ""

    #Save password to a temporary file
    echo "${password}" > /tmp/password.txt

    #Load password from file
    password=`cat /tmp/password.txt`

    if [ "${password}" == "${EXPECTED_PASS}" ]
    then
        echo "Access granted"
    else
        echo "Access denied"
    fi


else
    echo "Directory not found."
fi
```

Usually it's not a good idea to store passwords as plain text. It's better to encrypt them or at least perform a hash operation over them:

```
EXPECTED_PASS=`echo "FooBar" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d" "`
...
#Save password to a temporary file
echo "${password}"  | md5sum | cut -f1 -d" " > /tmp/password.txt

#Load password from file
password=`cat /tmp/password.txt`
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: @Penguin: Do you understand *why* redent84 has suggest that line for storing the password? In particular do you understand the purpose of `md5sum` and how to check the users later input for a match?